# Ruby: Hashmap have value as function and its evaluating the function

Tags: ruby

I have a hashmap as below

```rb
func_hash = {
          "update" =>  update(),
          "delete" =>  delete(),
          "get" => get()
        }
```

The behaviour that I am observing is , while ruby trying to read this line, its also calling the function update().

How can I make it work like, call the function only when I call it with specific key like

```
func_hash["delete"]
```

Any help, much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

you could do something like

```
func_hash = {
  "update" => lambda { update() },
  "delete" => lambda { delete() },
  "get" => lambda { get() }
}

func_hash["delete"].call
```

Comment: Or even a whitelisted version of `func_hash = Hash.new { |h, k| public_send(k) }`. Assuming they don't need `#each`, `#keys`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use a lambda like Ursus suggested to just store the name of the function in the hash and use `public_send`:

```
func_hash = {
  "update" => [:update],
  "delete" => [:delete],
  "get" => [:get],
  "complex" => [:method_name, 'argument', 'another_argument']
}

public_send(*func_hash['complex'])
#=> would call `method_name('argument', 'another_argument')`
```